# Taking a screenshot (within X)

Tags: screenshot, xorg

How can I take a screenshot in X.org?

I am unsure if the Print Screen button will "just work" and I don't know how I would go about testing it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The most commonly used Linux application for taking screen-shots is called `scrot`

You can install it with for Debian:

`sudo apt-get install scrot`

Or for Arch:

`sudo pacman -S scrot`

A screenshot is taken by typing:

`scrot output-file.png`

If you want to bind `scrot` to the `print screen` key then that will need to be controlled by your window manager.

Comment: Scrot is quicker and smaller than ImageMagick - 1MB compared to 43MB.

Answer (score 6):

I found a great answer to this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10609516/252223), it is worth repeating.

> This can be achieved with ImageMagick. Install by running the command
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install imagemagick
> ```
>
> To grab all desktop just type
>
> ```
> import -window root screen.png
> ```
>
> Or you can do it with a delay of 5 seconds
>
> ```
> sleep 5; import -window root screen.png
> ```

Comment: I wonder whether we could bind this to a key combo; anyone?

Comment: @AlexChamberlain: This is dependant on the WM that is being used.

Comment: @AlexChamberlain there is an answer as to how to do that [here](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/391/181)

Comment: -1 I despise ImageMagick and all of its derivatives/relatives. It's a kick in the pants to install, and it's even worse to fix if something breaks.

Comment: @Jivings I guess if you're using your window manager's keybindings; I would think most people use `xbindkeys` though

Comment: FYI: https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-1749/Imagemagick.html

Answer (score 0):

I use 'xwd'.  For example, one I just did:  `xwd | xwdtopnm > dw.ppm`
The only downside I know of with xwd is that you need some other utility to convert its output to something understood by anything other than 'xwud'.

Answer (score 0):

This is the perl6 script I use to take ***root area window*** or ***delay*** ScreenShots using import:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl6
use v6;

sub message(Str $file) {
  run <xmessage -nearmouse -timeout 3>, "Screenshot saved in $file";
}

sub print_window(Str $file) {
  qx{xprop -root | grep "_NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW(WINDOW)"} ~~ /(0x\d*).*$/;
  run <import -window>, $0, $file;
  message($file);
}

sub MAIN( Str $option where $option ∈ <root area window delay> ) {
  my $today = DateTime.now( formatter => { 
        sprintf "%04d_%02d_%02d_%02d:%02d:%02d", 
                .year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute, .second 
       } );
  my $file  = "$*HOME/Dades/Imatges/ScreenShots/$today.png";

  given $option {
    when 'root'   { run <import -window root>, $file; message($file) }
    when 'area'   { run "import", $file             ; message($file) }
    when 'window' { print_window($file)                              }
    when 'delay'  { sleep 5; print_window($file)                     }
    default       { say 'Something went wrong'      ; exit           }
  }
}
```

These are the key bindings in i3 to run the script:

```
bindsym $mod+Print exec Print_Screen root 
bindsym --release $mod+Shift+Print exec Print_Screen area
bindsym $mod+Mod1+Print exec Print_Screen delay
bindsym $mod+Control+Print exec Print_Screen window
```