# Screen shot in Lubuntu

Tags: lxde, screenshot, lubuntu

I'm using Lubuntu 11.10 and when I press the `PrtSc` key I get a screen-shot automatically, without confirmation. The problem is that sometimes I press it accidentally and a lot of JPEG files are created on my home directory.

So I would like to install a program to control screen-shots. What is the best LXDE native one for this? I don't want to install many libraries or Gnome ones.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Taking a screenshot (within X)](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/42677/taking-a-screenshot-within-x)

Comment: @jasonwryan the answer of that question was `scrot` which is not a interactive program, not what the OP want I guess

Comment: Taking a screenshot in X: there are only so many ways to ask the same question, IMO...

Comment: I found many programs to do this but since that I'm using LXDE (Lubuntu) I don't want to install a lot of stuffs related to Gnome, for example. For example, I use Leafpad instead of Gedit, it is the standard editor. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe [Shutter](http://shutter-project.org/), it has a few GNOME dependencies however (some are optional).

> Shutter is a feature-rich screenshot program. You can take a screenshot of a specific area, window, your whole screen, or even of a website – apply different effects to it, draw on it to highlight points, and then upload to an image hosting site, all within one window. Shutter is free, open-source, and licensed under GPL v3.

Or you could write a script that asks for confirmation and bind this to the `PrtSc` key.